# GCP Pub/Sub: Life of a Message

Tags: google-cloud-platform, streaming, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm trying to learn about GCP Pub/Sub and I have a problem about the **life of a message** in Pub/Sub. In fact, I used [this article](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/architecture) as my reference. And in this article, they said:

> Once at least one subscriber for each subscription has acknowledged the message, Pub/Sub deletes the message from storage.

So my **first question** is: for example I have a **Subscription** A which connects to **Subscriber** X et **Subscriber** Y. According to the docs, when the **Subscriber** X received the message and it sends an ACK to the **Subscription** A, the Pub/Sub will delete the message from storage without considering if the **Subscriber** Y received or not the message. In other words, Pub/Sub doesn't care if all subscribers have received messages or not, just one subscriber gets the message and Pub/Sub will delete the message from storage? Am I right, please?

Then, in the following part of the article, the article said:

> Once all subscriptions on a topic have acknowledged a message, the message is asynchronously deleted from the publish message source and from storage.

And I feel a little bit confuse here. What I understood is that, for instance, I have a topic that has N subscriptions, each subscription has M subscriber, Pub/Sub just needs to known that for each subscription, at least one subscriber has acknowledged the message, it'll delete the message from storage. Am I right, please?

I also found that in the documentation, we have two concepts: **Publishing Forwarder** and **Subscribing Forwarder**. So may I ask some last questions:

- What is the relationship between **Subscription**, **Publishing Forwarder** and **Subscribing Forwarder**? (for example, a **Subscription** consists only one **Publishing Forwarder** and one **Subscribing Forwarder**?)
- The relationship between **Publishing Forwarder** and **Subscribing Forwarder** is one-to-one or one-to-many or many-to-one or many-to-many, please?
- Can a **Subscriber** be associated with many **Subscription** or not, please?
- Once a **Subscriber** consumes a message (here I say this message is not duplicated, it has no copy, it is unique), is it possible to this **Subscriber** re-consumes/re-reads exactly this message?

If I misunderstand something, please, point it out for me, I really appreciate that.

Thank you guys !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite a bit to unpack here. It is best not to think of a **subscription** as attaching to **subscribers** and also to understand that these two things are different. A *subscription* is a named entity that wants to receive all messages published to a topic. A *subscriber* is an actual client running to receive and process messages on behalf of a subscription. A topic can have many subscriptions. A subscription can have many subscribers. If there are multiple subscribers in a subscription, then, assuming there are no duplicate deliveries and subscriber ack all messages received, each message published to a topic will be delivered to one subscriber for the subscription. This is called *load balancing*: the processing of messages is spread out over many subscribers. If a topic has multiple subscriptions, each with one subscriber, then every subscriber will receive all messages. This is called *fan out*: each subscriber receives the complete set of messages published. Of course, it is possible to combine these two and have more than one subscriber for each subscription, in which case each message will be delivered to one subscriber for each subscription.

Forwarders are just the servers that are responsible for delivering messages. A publishing forwarder receives messages from publishers and a subscribing forwarder sends messages to subscribers. All of the relationships along the path of delivering a message, from publisher to publishing forwarder, publishing forwarder to subscribing forwarder, and subscribing forwarder to subscriber, can be many-to-many relationships.

A subscriber is associated with a single subscription. However, a job running could have multiple subscribers running within it, e.g., one could instantiate the subscriber client library several times on different subscriptions.

All of the above assumed an important caveat: assuming there are no duplicate deliveries. In general, Cloud Pub/Sub guarantees at least once delivery. That means that even a message that was properly acked by a subscriber could be redelivered--either to the same subscriber or a different subscriber--in which case the subscriber needs to ack the message on the subsequent delivery. Generally, duplicate rates should be very low, in the 0.1% range for a well-behaved subscriber that is acking messages before the ack deadline expires.

Comment: Thank @Kamal, so I do believe that I had a misunderstanding at the very beginning, I've thought that if there are multiple subscribers in a subscription, all the subscribers would receive the **same complete** set of messages published. But this is not the case. So if I do a comparison between **Pub/Sub** and **Kafka**: the case where we have multiple subscribers in a subscription is like a **consumer group** which is a group of **consumers** that share the same group id. Because in Kafka, the records will also be **load-balanced** effectively over the **consumer instances**. Am I correct?

Comment: And I have a one last question, please: in the case of message duplicated, and if we find out that the issue is on the **subscriber** side, can we use more subscribers for the subscription to resolve the problem? And if yes, why is this work, please? Many thank!!

Comment: Yes compared to Kafka, a subscriber is a consumer and a subscription is a consumer group. With regard to your other question, what do you mean by "issue is on the subscriber side?" That the subscriber is overloaded? Has a bug?

Comment: Sorry for my unclear question, what I mean is that, on the subscriber side, we find out that there is a single message delivered multiple times (based on the messageID provided with the message) for example. So besides the increasing the acknowledgement deadline which could solve this problem, do we have any other solutions, please?

Comment: Redelivery is going to happen from time to time as Pub/Sub does not currently support exactly-once delivery. Increasing the ack deadline can help and if your subscribers are overwhelmed in terms of CPU or other resources, then having more subscribers could help. But no matter what, duplicates will still happen at times.